# Could javascript simple email obfuscators work?

Tags: javascript, obfuscation

I'm working on a site that will store thousands of records of email addresses for public reference and, since the server resources are pretty low and the load will be pretty high, I was thinking about writing a simple email obfuscator.

It should work more or less like this:

- An encryption key is generated;
- PHP encrypts the email;
- on mouse move, js makes an ajax call to a controller that gives it back the encryption key;
- The email is decrypted by javascript, which then puts it in the right DOM element;

The key will be generated on the fly (hashing the client name?).

The thing is: I would know how to break this and a similar class of obfuscators, also security by obscurity and so on but: is it okay to expect a decent degree of security with such a method?

Also, do most scraping spiders have simulated mouse movements and so on?

Sorry, maybe it's a dumb question, but I'm really no ace in cryptography-related fields and this is the first time I have to do something similar.

Client proposed an image containing the email, but the idea makes me frown even more than obfuscation.

---

Also I would like to know, if you feel particularly kind, whether parts of my procedure are redundant/useless. I have some ideas (eg, if the spider simulates a movement, what does encryption add to it? But then again, maybe it's better if the ajax data is not recognized as an email), but that's a domain I never explored before.

Comment: It's getting kind of old, but [according to this article](http://techblog.tilllate.com/2008/07/20/ten-methods-to-obfuscate-e-mail-addresses-compared/), you should be totally fine as is.

Comment: Wow, those stats are incredibly encouraging - almost looks like I tried too hard.

Comment: It all depends on the determination of the person trying to scrape your site.  The article @sdleihssirhc linked to, basically shows two methods that I can see. Both of these methods are overcome with a dom based scraper.  Even without the dom, a regex based approach would work and after the fact it'd be fairly simple to remove the "null" text from the middle of the email addresses.  The ROT13 approach requires the browser is smart enough to decrypt the email, therefore a bot would exploit that fact to get the email.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your end goal is to display email addresses on a public web page, not requiring user authentication, or captcha, and prevent spiders from crawling your pages to collect the email addresses for purposes of spamming, the answer is Yes and No.

It all depends on the sophistication of the bot crawling your site. The fact of the matter is, if it's available in the web browser DOM, a bot can extract it from your page.

One way I can think of to prevent this, is to show images of the email addresses as hyperlinks, and when someone clicks an image of an email address you prompt them to answer a CAPTCHA, and you then make an ajax call to bring the email address down to the client browser.  You clearly need to secure the request to get the email address, if possible you can send it back to the browser when they successfully answer the CAPTCHA.

As far as mouse movements goes it would depend.  If I specifically want to scrape your site I would inspect your html and javascript code such that my bot would do whatever it had to do to reach it's goal.  A captcha is probably the only thing that could stop me from extracting the data I need.  Or a really elaborate system for skewing your html structure such that there was no consistent structure for me to code against.

I don't think there is any cryptography/security based approach you can take to this, since you are publicly displaying the data.  Even if you were to protect the data with a password, you would have to give the password to someone to view the data.  In which case if they were writing a bot, their bot would simply use that password to scrape your site.

CAPTCHA is probably the only good way to protect these email addresses and still display them publicly as images. Although simply creating an image with an email address won't protect you from everyone, it will protect you from most.  If you want you can get more sophisticated with it, by almost turning the email address images into their own "captcha" like images, but these will hurt the user experience.

There isn't a perfect solution, except to not show the email address and have a form on your website that people can use to send the emails.

Additionally, since you said you will have few resources but a lot of load, your suggested approach would probably be too cpu intensive for your servers since you would need to encrypt each email address one at a time anytime is was displayed on any page.

Hope this helps.

Mark

Answer (score 2):

As sdleihssirhc pointed out, simple obfuscation is actually quite effective. Here is a simple PHP function that uses ROT13 to obfuscate mailto links:

```
/**
 * GET OBFUSCATED MAILTO
 *
 * Takes an email and returns HTML to render the mailto: link in javascript.  This way, the
 * plaintext email is not in the page source, but is in the generated source.  Regular users can
 * copy and paste and click the mailto: link as normal, but spiders will face a major hurdle.
 *
 * @see String.prototype.rot13()
 *
 * @param string $email The address which the mailto: link will point to.
 * @param string $text (optional) The anchor text.  Default: same as $email.
 * @return string HTML with javascript to render mailto: link from obfuscated source.
 */
function getObfuscatedMailto($email, $text = false){

    $text = $text ? $text : $email;
    $link = '<a href="mailto:'.$email.'">'.$text.'</a>';

    // ROT13 encode javascript string
    $link = str_rot13($link);
    $link = str_replace("'","\\'",$link);

    $html = "<script>var s='$link';document.write(s.rot13());</script>";
    return $html;
}
```

And here is the javascript:

```
/**
 * ROT 13
 * 
 * Credit: Jonas Raoni Soares Silva
 *         http://jsfromhell.com/string/rot13
 */
String.prototype.rot13 = function(){
  return this.replace(/[a-zA-Z]/g, function(c){
      return String.fromCharCode((c <= "Z" ? 90 : 122) >= (c = c.charCodeAt(0) + 13) ? c : c - 26);
  });
};
```

Comment: It may work in general, but if I code my bot to call this rot13 method, my bot will be able to pull the email address data. So it depends if you are looking for a solution that will work in general, or a solution that will work against someone specifically trying to scrape your site.  As a general solution i'm sure this is fine.